# How do I embed a Facebook profile on an external website?

Tags: facebook

How do I embed a Facebook profile on an external website; including status updates, fans, and everything.

Comment: Do you want to put the whole profile as it is? What width and height will you allow? Are these information public?

Comment: Zakaria, there was a Fan Box badget in 2009, and I can't find that now.. Width and height doesn't matter, for example 5-600 pixel width and height is OK, but I don't want to use iframe if it is not needed.

Comment: Most likely at least some parts of the profile will not be public.. So you will have to create an App in the developer section (just get an app id, etc..) and use the API to query and import the information...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a list of all the current Social Plugins you can implement/display on your website through Facebook:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/